# Having issues with re.findall

Tags: python, python-2.7

Got the following code

```
title = re.findall('<title>(.*?)</title>',content)
```

Works as expected, but won't return anything when facing the following structure:

```
<title>


xxxxxxx


</title>
```

i.e. when there is some free space between the `<title>.`

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the [`re.S`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S) (dot-all) flag to have `.` match over newlines:

```
>>> import re
>>> content = """
... <title>
...
...
... xxxxxxx
...
...
... </title>
... """
>>> title = re.findall('<title>(.*?)</title>', content, re.S)
>>> title
['\n\n\nxxxxxxx\n\n\n']
>>> title[0].strip()
'xxxxxxx'
>>>
```

---

*Note:* An alternate way of setting the dot-all flag is by placing `(?s)` at the start of the Regex pattern:

```
title = re.findall('(?s)<title>(.*?)</title>', content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this [re.S](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S)

```
re.findall('<title>(.*?)</title>', content, re.S)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
<title>\n*(.*)\n*</title>
```

Will match:

`xxxxxxx`

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/qJ1pJ0).

Comment: maybe a `<title>\n*(.*)\n*</title>` would be more appropriate, making it closer to the original.